# How to replace vowels with number

Tags: go

Is there any way in Go to search for vowels and replace it with numbers in a given string? the program should randomly replace the vowels with numbers and display the formatted string

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"strings"
)

func main() {

vowels := map[rune]rune{
'a': '3',
'e': '2',
'i': '1',   
}

var s string
s = strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
if u, ok := vowels[r]; ok {
    return u
}
return r
}, s)
fmt.Println(s)
}
```

but still it is not printing the random strings .. please suggest

Comment: A basic example https://play.golang.org/p/vQtRiu9dNl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest using [`strings.Map`](https://godoc.org/strings#Map) for this:

```
s = strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
   switch r {
     case 'a':
       return '3'
     case 'e':
       return '2'
     // etc.
     default:
       return r
   }
}, s)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/D66J5hZsNs

With a slight modification, if you need to dynamically set the replacement values, you could store the vowels in a map. For example:

```
vowels := map[rune]rune{
    'a': '3',
    'e': '2',
}

s = strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
    if u, ok := vowels[r]; ok {
        return u
    }
    return r
}, s)
```

Comment: instead of fixing/hardcoding the numbers with vowels , can they be generated randomly and then replace ?

Comment: @user2315104: Yes, modify the 2nd example: randomly generate the `vowels` map.

Comment: @user2315104: your string `s` that you are passing to `strings.Replace` is empty

Comment: here is my string : s = "adsad" but everytime it prints  : 3ds3d after replacement ... any issue ?

Comment: @user2315104: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. You might want to open up another question with the code you are using.